# When opening "cmd" in Windows, are you accessing the Kernel?

Tags: ruby, cmd, kernel

I have only a basic understanding that the Kernel is the central part of the operating system.

How close are you to that Kernel when you open up cmd (Run -> cmd)?

I'm learning Ruby right now and I read the following statement:

"When printing to output using the Kernel methods puts and p, they call to_s and inspect on their argument for you."

What I am assuming from this is that they are talking about when you run p or puts in cmd.

Please clarify in semi-layman's terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are no closer to the operating system's kernel when entering commands in cmd than when writing a letter in word.

There is no relationship between the ruby module `Kernel` and the operating system kernel - they just happen to have the same name

Comment: Ok great. After reading this, the original sentence got much clearer. It says "Kernel methods." I read just as it as "When printing to output using the Kernel." and got stuck there. But now it makes sense, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel is a normal English word. Ruby's `Kernel` module has about as much to do with the Windows kernel as an apple at your local fruit stand has to do with an iPhone.

The Windows kernel and Ruby's `Kernel` module are both called "kernel", because that's the English word that best describes them, not because they are in any way related.

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.exe` is just an application like notepad, excel or others.

On older Windows (Win98 and below), `command.com` was used instead, which is indeed "below Windows" ("nearer to the hardware")